# Can't find a way to install gettext from PIP virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip, gettext

Overall I'm trying to use a module in Django that helps with translating pages, but I don't have installed and can't do it through pip install *package*.

I've tried the fllowing:

```
pip install gettext
```

That returns that could not find a version that requires the...

I also downloaded the tar.gz file from the official website, yet when I try to install it localy the error:

```
python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 windows
```

Comes up. Been reading, trying to fix the second error or possible solutions, installed ez_update, updatade all packages, made a rollback and I don't know what to do anymore, any help?

Comment: You may want to look here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm, gettext for windows is a little different than a Unix based environment

Comment: what does translation refers to here? are you talking about translation from one lang to another or just unicode

Comment: I'm trying to use a module of django that translates websites based on gettext

Comment: @NickHale I went by that page but didn't pay much attention because I need to install it on a virtual environment, which I don't know if I will be able to do it! Thanks, will take a look regardless

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows there are pre-comiled binaries so you don't have to actually install.

Answer (score 4):

The package *gettext* is available as `python-gettext` in [Python pypi](https://pypi.python.org)

Please use

`pip install python-gettext`

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue and what worked for me eventually is the following:

1. download gettext-runtime-0.17.zip and gettext-tools-0.17.zip (or the latest version) from here:
   http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/
2. Place both directories in your project directory (say myProject)
3. Now, in each of these folders there is a bin folder. Go into it and copy the address. Each would look sth like:

   - C:\myProject\gettext-runtime-0.17\bin
   - C:\myProject\gettext-tools-0.17\bin
4. Go into: control panel > System > Advanced System settings > Environment variables. In system variables, choose Path and click
   'edit'.
5. Paste **both** addresses at the end, like this:

;C:\myProject\gettext-runtime-0.17\bin;C:\myProject\gettext-tools-0.17\bin

(don't forget the semicolon after the last existing item)

6. Activate your virtualenv and run the makemessages command. It should work.